# Collect keystroke events with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I would like to collect individual keystroke events (keydown and keyup) in a chat client. I have the following basic code, which sets up a chat app and sends each message to a mongoDB cluster. I would like to create a new record for each keystroke event, rather than each message. Below is what I tried, to at least print the keystroke event to the console, but event that doesn't seem to be working. Below are the rudimentary index.html, index.js, and a mongoose Schema in messages.js.

**What I've tried:** In `index.html`, I added:

```
     var input = document.getElementById('input');

      // DOES NOT PRINT KEYSTROKES
      input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            console.log(`key=${event.key},code=${event.code}`);
        });
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

      #form { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); padding: 0.25rem; position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; display: flex; height: 3rem; box-sizing: border-box; backdrop-filter: blur(10px); }
      #input { border: none; padding: 0 1rem; flex-grow: 1; border-radius: 2rem; margin: 0.25rem; }
      #input:focus { outline: none; }
      #form > button { background: #333; border: none; padding: 0 1rem; margin: 0.25rem; border-radius: 3px; outline: none; color: #fff; }

      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages > li { padding: 0.5rem 1rem; }
      #messages > li:nth-child(odd) { background: #efefef; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
      <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>
      var socket = io();

      var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
      var form = document.getElementById('form');
      var input = document.getElementById('input');

      // DOES NOT PRINT KEYSTROKES
      input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
            console.log(`key=${event.key},code=${event.code}`);
        });

      form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (input.value) {
          socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
          input.value = '';
        }
      });

      socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.textContent = msg;
        messages.appendChild(item);
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Msg = require('./models/messages');
const mongoDB = 'mongodb+srv://Adam-gk:<mypassword>@cluster0.oqwbc.mongodb.net/message-database?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).then(()=>{
  console.log('connected to db');
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', msg => {
    const message = new Msg({msg});
    message.save().then(()=>{
      io.emit('chat message', msg);
    })    
  });
});

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.IO server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});
```

models/messages.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const msgSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        msg: {
            type:String,
            required:true
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    }
);

const Msg = mongoose.model('msg', msgSchema);
module.exports = Msg;
```

Comment: keyloggers in a chat app. not sus at all.

Comment: @MichaelMano Is “sus” short for “suspect”? This project is for my dissertation, creating an experiment to test online collaboration.

Comment: @Adam_G so you're having problems getting the "keydown" event to print anything? that's a javascript and HTML issue.

Comment: Have you checked if `input` is referencing the input element from the DOM correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by that? How would I check that?

Comment: @Adam_G try adding a `console.log(input)` immediately after assigning the variable and what is the output you get?

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't output anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code to `console.log` isn't working then it leads me to believe that there is an issue with your reference to the input element in the DOM. The code may be executing quickly before the browser has rendered the HTML elements into the DOM and thus the event is not being attached properly.

There is an event that fires off when the browser has finally rendered all the DOM elements. I think once your codes fires after this event the keydown event should work properly.

try commenting out these two lines (like so):

```
// var input = document.getElementById('input');

// DOES NOT PRINT KEYSTROKES
// input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
//  console.log(`key=${event.key},code=${event.code}`);
// });
```

and add this to your script tags:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
 var input = document.getElementById('input');

 input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
   console.log(`key=${event.key},code=${event.code}`);
 });
})
```

Does this help?

Its general best practice to always wait for this event. Most frameworks abstract this away for you and you no longer see it but you're handcrafting javascript this is something you have to add yourself.

**Additional Info for OP:**
To send a message from the front-end (html file) to the server you emit a message, add something like this inside of your input's event handler:

```js
socket.emit('the name of your new event goes here', /* something that has a value here */);
```

then on your **server** you need to add a new event that listens for this new chat event named `'the name of your new event goes here'` for example so:

```js
//.          v------- the event name is here       v---- msg is here  
socket.on('the name of your new event goes here', msg => {
  const message = new Msg({msg});
  // do something with this message... like `console.log(message)` ‍♂️
   
});
```

be sure to add that code inside of the (again, **server side code)**:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => { /* inside here with the other events */ })
```

Comment: Interesting. What you're saying makes sense. For some reason, though, this isn't printing anything to the console. I've tried both `node index` and `nldemon index`. It does print the outputs in `index.js`

Comment: @Adam_G the output should be in the web browser console

Comment: Ohhhh!! I feel foolish. So this does output the correct keys/keycodes. Any idea how to send them to mongoDB (through socket.io if need be)?

Comment: add this `socket.emit('name your message here? like keydown?', /* something that has a value here*/);` inside of the event listener for your `input` field. I've added comments and placeholder values to that code example btw. good luck!

Comment: i'll update my answer to include more info

Comment: This looks very helpful, thank you! I'll just need to work on sending it to mongo

Comment: @Adam_G cool, I'm sure that has something to do with your model, aka `const message = new Msg({msg});`

Comment: Right, makes sense!